# 404 when passing two parameters to an api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I´m trying to make a simple api on .net core 3.1, I deleted the wheather thing that comes from default. I put a new starting point but despite many efforts and changes, I still get an 404

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
                endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

In properties, start explorer:

```
api/Servicio/GetServicio/tecnico/Pedro/semanaDelAno/8
```

Controller

```
[Route("api/Servicio")]
    public class ServicioController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public ServicioController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // POST: api/PostServicio
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Servicio>> PostServicio(Servicio servicio)
        {
            _context.Servicio.Add(servicio);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            
            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetServicio), new { id = servicio.Id }, servicio);
        }


        // GET: api/GetServicio/5
        //[HttpGet("{tecnico}/{semanaDelAno}")]
        [HttpGet("GetServicio/{tecnico}/{semanaDelAno}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Servicio>> GetServicio(string tecnico, int semanaDelAno)
        {
            var servicio = await _context.Servicio.FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Tecnico == tecnico && i.SemanaDelAno == semanaDelAno);

            if (servicio == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return servicio;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming  tecnico=Pedro and semanaDelAno=8,  you have to use this url

```
~/api/Servicio/GetServicio/Pedro/8
```

for GetServicio action:

```
[HttpGet("GetServicio/{tecnico}/{semanaDelAno}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Servicio>> GetServicio(string tecnico, int semanaDelAno)
{
.... your code
}
```